# My suffix is an obsolete exercise

Tags: riddle, word

My prefix may well be you, and is followed by u
My suffix is an obsolete exercise
My infix is better when hard
My whole is often done in a line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it MANUFACTURE

> Prefix MAN and U

> Suffix not sure about this ACTURE?

> Infix FACT, in the hard facts.

> When goods are manufactured they are done in a line

Comment: Well.  That was quick.  What gave it away?

Comment: The first clue was a dead give away.

Comment: Ah, well.  Tried not to make it too hard.  Wound up making it too easy.  Suffix is not the one I was thinking, but is excellent nonetheless.  Try smaller.